# Remove a full string of text from a partial string match and not creating a new file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently trying to remove a full string of text from multiple files off a partial match.

For instance, I have a header and a footer with the characters `0*5` in that exact order. I want to completely remove the headers and footers from my files in a specific folder without changing the file name. I've found and tried sever `Get-Content myFile.txt` and `Set-Content newFile.txt`.

My files are located in a folder, so I am calling them from an "*". They all have different names. I'm am trying to remove all of the headers and footers all in one pass through PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of losing the originals, so I use the long method:

```
$ListofFiles = Get-ChildItem c:\windows\logs\* -include *.txt

ForEach ($item in $ListOfFiles){
    $FileContent = Get-Content "$item.txt"
    Rename-Item -path "c:\windows\logs\$item.txt" -newname "$item.old"
    ForEach ($line in $FileContent) {
        If ($Line -like "*whatever i am looking for*") {
            Write-host "Found the entry i was looking for"
        }
        else {
            $Line | Out-File "c:\windows\logs\$item.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in your `$item` strings - single-quoted strings don't interpolate variables, so you will always read and write `$item.txt` as a literal filename, instead of the loop variable content.txt

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.... when I pasted it they where all double quoted....